# Dynamic changing interval input property in NgbCarousel directive

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

I am trying to make carousel whose speed can be controlled dynamically by user inputs (for example buttons). I have targeted the **interval** input property as instructed in the ng-bootstrap [carousel API](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/carousel/api) but for some reason, I find that the speed of the slides does not change dynamically in response to user input when the carousel is already running, unless I stop and restart the carousel. I used the code below  similar to what can be found in ngx-bootstrap dynamic carousel [here](http://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/carousel) ( which I was using before)

```
 <!-- Template carousel.html -->

<ngb-carousel #flash="ngbCarousel" [interval]="speed">
<ng-template ngbSlide>
<img src="https://lorempixel.com/900/500?r=1" alt="Random first slide">
<div class="carousel-caption">
  <h3>First slide label</h3>
  <p>Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue mollis interdum.</p>
</div>
</ng-template>
<ng-template ngbSlide>
<img src="https://lorempixel.com/900/500?r=2" alt="Random second slide">
<div class="carousel-caption">
  <h3>Second slide label</h3>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
</div>
</ng-template>
  <ng-template ngbSlide>
<img src="https://lorempixel.com/900/500?r=3" alt="Random third slide">
<div class="carousel-caption">
  <h3>Third slide label</h3>
  <p>Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur.</p>
</div>
</ng-template>
</ngb-carousel>


<div>   
<button type="button" (click)="flash.pause()" class="btn btn-warning">
  Pause</button>
<button type="button" (click)="flash.cycle()" class="btn btn-success">
   Start</button>
<input type="number" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="speed">
</div>

/* Typescript carousel.ts */    

import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
selector: 'ngbd-carousel-basic',
templateUrl: './carousel.html'
})
export class NgbdCarouselBasic {

 public speed : number;

}
```

Can someone please show me a way make button or a form input dynamically change the speed of the carousel at runtime or is this feature impossible currently in ng-bootstrap?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the current (as of `1.0.0-alpha.28`) [ng-bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io) implementation the dynamic interval change won't be picked up unless you pause / restart. So what you are observing is a limitation of the current implementation.

You can open an issue in https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/issues to request for this case to be supported.

Comment: I thought as much. I think this feature should be supported already!

Comment: @dtechplus I've opened https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/issues/1690 to track this